# How do I query in natural=strait from OSM databse?

Tags: openstreetmap, sql

I'm trying to query in straits, fjords, and bays from a PostGIS Openstreemap database. The straits I'm looking for are tagged natural=bay, natural=strait, and natural=fjord.

I used the following code:

```
(SELECT
        way, natural
      FROM planet_osm_line
      WHERE natural IN ('bay', 'strait', 'fjord')
    ) AS straits
```

But, it returns:

```
 Postgis Plugin: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 3:           FROM planet_osm_line
                  ^

in executeQuery Full sql was: 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT
            way, natural
          FROM planet_osm_line
          WHERE natural IN ('bay', 'strait', 'fjord')
        ) AS straits LIMIT 0'
```

I am able to query docks / piers. And the SQL I used is very similar so I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

This is what I used for docks and it works:

```
(SELECT
        way, man_made
      FROM planet_osm_line
      WHERE man_made IN ('pier')
    ) AS docks
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Natural is a reserved keyword in PostgreSQL [see full list](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and it has a special meaning in SQL JOIN

> "a shorthand for a USING list that mentions all columns in the two
>   tables that have the same names"

Write your query as

> SELECT "natural" FROM ...

and it should work.